# How to do Php Security check for input fields and input treatment?

Tags: php, security, validation

How to do Php Security check for input user fields and input user treatment(please if you can solve example1+2)?

**Example1: check if user insert url or something else:**

```
<label>url: </label>
<input type="text">
```

**Example2: check if user insert html or something else**

```
<label>paste html: </label>
<textarea></textarea>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** For the validation of URLs :

```
$validUrl = strpos($url, "http://") === 0;
if(!$validUrl) $url = "http://".$url;
```

When the link is return to the user, use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

**2.** For the validation of HTML code, use a lib like http://htmlpurifier.org/.

```
<?php
require_once 'htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($_GET['dirty_html']);
echo $clean_html;
?>
```

With the input :

```
<img src="test.gif" onload="alert('xss')"/>
```

The result is :

```
<img src="test.gif" alt="test.gif" />
```

Comment: Thanks,does simple dom have filtering like html purifier?

Comment: what about if user insert www.yahoo.com or yahoo.com your code not work

Comment: For the URLs, you should force "http://" otherwise links like "jAvAsCrIpT://%0Aalert('xss')" can be passed

Comment: Filtering HTML goes beyond matching certain tags. Many HTML tags support js events that can be malicious. Support HTML as input only if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

USE regex to validate your input

see

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/regular-expressions-php

http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html

http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Not only should nobody ever, under any circumstances attempt to validate or parse html/xml using regular expressions, I can't believe you missed http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @Jack, because it is very widely regarded a very bad idea. xml/html is not just text and parsing xml/html with regex is slow and unless you are a rockstar regex expert, your regex is going to suck. For simpler text though, regex is the shizzle

Comment: @Jack : recursive encapsulation, ton of tags, ton of attributes ... and the code need to be maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

For string filtering/validating we use [RegExp](http://lv.php.net/pcre) and for html filtering/validating we use [DOM extension](http://lv.php.net/dom)

Comment: You should provide a regex (it's easy to make a broken one) / Do you have any code sample of validation using the DOM api? This seems ambitious.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid the most often to use regex for input validation which are consuming lot of CPU. Since PHP 5.2 there is filter_var for email, url, ip, string, int, float sanitize and validate.

```
// Remove wrong characters   
$myURL = filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

// Notice the ===
// If we were checking integer input and imagine zero was a valid input
// do !filter_var($myNumber , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) will display "Invalid Number"
if (filter_var($myURL , FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
    echo "Invalid URL"
else
    echo "Valid URL"
```

If you have lot of inputs, you can use the [filter_input_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php).